# How Change value of "minimize-to-application" in Dock Preferences

Tags: swift, objective-c, dock

Searching about CoreDockPreferences, I found These private system APIs [coredock.h](https://gist.github.com/w0lfschild/90db263867f469738c01e9e2d937f874)

I'm trying to change the value of Minimize To App using CoreDockSetPreferences, but it's not working

Below is my Interface and Implementation in Obj-c:

```
@interface Symbolic : NSObject

extern void CoreDockSetPreferences(CFDictionaryRef preferenceDict);

- (void) setDictionaryDock: (CFDictionaryRef)dockDict;

@end

@implementation Symbolic

-(void) setDictionaryDock: (CFDictionaryRef)dockDict
{
    CoreDockSetPreferences(dockDict);
}
```

And Here is how I call and pass dock.plist Dictionary Changed in Swift:

```
func dockPrefChange(){
    if let dir = FileManager.default.urls(for: .libraryDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first {
        let dockPlistPath = dir.appendingPathComponent("Preferences", isDirectory: true).appendingPathComponent("com.apple.dock.plist", isDirectory: false)
        guard let dockDictionary = NSMutableDictionary(contentsOf: dockPlistPath) else {return}
        dockDictionary["minimize-to-application"] = 1
        Symbolic().setDictionaryDock(dockDictionary as CFDictionary)
    }
}
```

Comment: How is it "not working"? Is `CoreDockSetPreferences` executed? Is `dockDict` what is should be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks [Willeke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4244136/willeke) you're right.

DockDict was not what should be.
Reading more about, I answer the question.

Basically I follow the commented "sequence usage" found in coredock.h

```
// Example usage
/*
    CFArrayRef d = CFStringCreateArrayBySeparatingStrings(kCFAllocatorDefault, CFSTR("showRecents,showProcessIndicators,minimizeToApplication"), CFSTR(","));
    CFDictionaryRef dic;
    CoreDockCopyPreferences(d, &dic, nil);
 */
```

And re-create the code as below:

```
@implementation Symbolic

- (NSDictionary*) getDictionaryDock
{
    CFArrayRef d = CFStringCreateArrayBySeparatingStrings(kCFAllocatorDefault, CFSTR("showRecents,showProcessIndicators,minimizeToApplication"), CFSTR(","));
    CFDictionaryRef dic;
    CoreDockCopyPreferences(d, &dic, nil);
    NSDictionary *nsDictionary = (__bridge NSDictionary*)dic;
    return nsDictionary;
}

- (void) setDictionaryDock: (NSDictionary*) newDictionary
{
    CFDictionaryRef dict = (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)newDictionary;
    CoreDockSetPreferences(dict);
}
```

and in Swift:

```
public func setMinimizeToApp(value: Bool){
    if var dict = symbolic.getDictionaryDock() as? [String: Bool] {
        if dict["minimizeToApplication"] != value{
            dict["minimizeToApplication"] = value
            symbolic.setDictionaryDock(dict)
        }
    }
}
```